# Airflow: Is it possible to mark a DagRun as failed/kill it?

Tags: python, airflow

I want to programatically kill a dag run. How can I do it via the Python API or otherwise?

Comment: you can change state of task in a DAG, does it help ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should also be able to accomplish this with the Python API:

```
from airflow.models.dagrun import DagRun
from airflow.utils.state import DagRunState

dag_runs = DagRun.find(run_id='...')
assert len(dag_runs) == 1
dag_runs[0].set_state(DagRunState.FAILED)
```

Comment: This didnt seem to do anything for me, even tho theres no error

Answer (score 0):

You can change the state of DagRun via the [Modify a DAG run](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/update_dag_run_state)
endpoint of the Rest API

```
PATCH /dags/{dag_id}/dagRuns/{dag_run_id}
```

with payload:

```
{
"state": "failed"
}
```

Note that Airflow has official [Python SDK](https://github.com/apache/airflow-client-python) to interact with the API so you can also use [`update_dag_run_state`](https://github.com/apache/airflow-client-python/blob/master/airflow_client/docs/DAGRunApi.md#update_dag_run_state) :

```
import time
import airflow_client.client
from airflow_client.client.api import dag_run_api
from airflow_client.client.model.dag_run import DAGRun
from airflow_client.client.model.update_dag_run_state import UpdateDagRunState
from airflow_client.client.model.error import Error
from pprint import pprint
# Defining the host is optional and defaults to http://localhost/api/v1
# See configuration.py for a list of all supported configuration parameters.
configuration = client.Configuration(
    host = "http://localhost/api/v1"
)
# Configure HTTP basic authorization: Basic
configuration = client.Configuration(
    username = 'YOUR_USERNAME',
    password = 'YOUR_PASSWORD'
)

# Enter a context with an instance of the API client
with client.ApiClient(configuration) as api_client:
    # Create an instance of the API class
    api_instance = dag_run_api.DAGRunApi(api_client)
    dag_id = "dag_id_example" # str | The DAG ID.
    dag_run_id = "dag_run_id_example" # str | The DAG run ID.
    update_dag_run_state = UpdateDagRunState(
        state="failed",
    )

    try:
        # Modify a DAG run
        api_response = api_instance.update_dag_run_state(dag_id, dag_run_id, update_dag_run_state)
        pprint(api_response)
    except client.ApiException as e:
        print("Exception when calling DAGRunApi->update_dag_run_state: %s\n" % e)
```

Comment: I realise now that the error I get now is "The DAG (.dag) for {self} needs to be set". How can I determine the dag for the dagrun. Or otherwise set it?

Comment: Can you please clarify the question? You asked about error but your question was about "How to.." and doesn't contain any code sample. If you are asking about specific error then we need to see the code that produced it with traceback

Comment: Oh sorry, maybe I should have said I was tring to use the python SDK https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/dagrun/index.html#airflow.models.dagrun.DagRun.set_state, which does nothing. Then I tried to use update_state which actually throws that error. Maybe 2 qns. Isit possible to use the Python API https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/python-api-ref.html instead? Was trying to avoid needed to authenticate the request even when I am alr in airflow alr

Comment: Hmm just tried installing airflow-client-python and got `ERROR: No matching distribution found for airflow-client-python` hmm

Comment: Just to clarify My answer assumes that you are trying to set the state externally. If you are trying to do it within Airflow DAG then this answer is not the way to go. If the code I provided doesn't work for you then there is probably a bug and you can open a bug report in https://github.com/apache/airflow-client-python/issues so we can invistigate

Comment: Ok the usecase is I need a way to programatically kill dags within airflow, so I was trying that out, but if theres no way to do so, I am now also trying this API way. Just that cant seem to install the package on Python3.7.12

Comment: for that use case 0x5453 answer is more suitable. It's not a common use case of ETLs so there is no out of the box solution for this. Note that changing the status does not invoke the on_kill of the tasks so there are down side.